# Clearing QgsRubberBand

Tags: pyqgis, qgsrubberband

I have several tools working with QGIS rubberband
before activating my new map tool i want to make sure there is nothing on rubberband
previously up to QGIS 3.2 I was able to clean the rubberband via the following code

```
rbs = [ i for i in canvas.scene().items() if issubclass(type(i), qgis._gui.QgsRubberBand) ]
if len(rbs)>0:
    for rb in rbs:
        if rb in canvas.scene().items():
            canvas.scene().removeItem(rb)
```

This code no longer works(as QGIS adds some default rubberband and when I try this QGIS crashes
now the question is how to have similar functionality (cleaning map canvas from all rubberbands before starting)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to change this:

```py
for rb in rbs:
  if rb in canvas.scene().items():
     canvas.scene().removeItem(rb)
```

to this:

```py
for rb in rbs:
   rb.reset()
```